# Problem searching for Cyrillic characters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, utf-8, cyrillic

I have to work with the Cyrillic alphabet, I have problem with this alphabet in queries.

When I'm looking for a specific word, some characters work like wildcards and are not considered at all in the comparison. For example, in the following searches:

```
select * 
from Words 
where word = N'мон'
```

[image]

What is a solution for this problem?

Comment: What's the **datatype** of that column in the SQL Server table? You're searching correctly with the `N` prefix - but is the column the right datatype, too?

Comment: You need to provide the other words as text as I can't copy and paste from an image. Which is one reason why images should never be used for data.

Comment: You need to use a Cyrillic collation https://dbfiddle.uk/z19lT2DA in order for SQL Server to know how to compare them.

Comment: See for collation for example: https://sqlquantumleap.com/2019/03/13/differences-between-the-various-binary-collations-cultures-versions-and-bin-vs-bin2/

Comment: @jalalhojati - Can you do others a favor and post an answer to your own question saying *how* the problem was solved? That way, if someone comes across this post in the future, there's a solution right there. Thanks in advance.